# ChartJS Pie chart is too small on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am trying to make my ChartJS Pie chart responsive on mobile. All the labels and titles scale ok, but when it comes to the actual chart
[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SaFF.png).

This is what I am aiming for [it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po5UZ.png).

I tried changing aspect ratios and responsiveness true/false values, but that didn't do anything.

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

JS:

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Archivo";
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'pie',
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      data: {
          labels: ["Total Working Time", "Time Wasted On Scheduling"],
          datasets: [{
              data: [40-appendHours, 40-(40-appendHours)],
              backgroundColor: [
                '#73D500',
                '#FD4D7A',
              ],
              borderColor: [
                '#73D500',
                '#73D500'
              ],
              borderWidth: 5
          }]
      },
      options: {
        events: [],
        legend: {
          labels: {
            fontColor: '#44566c',
            fontSize: 15,
            fontStyle: "normal",
            fontFamily: "'Archivo', sans-serif"
          },
        },

        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Hours wasted by 1 person on scheduling per week',
          fontSize: 15,
          position: 'bottom',
          fontColor: '#44566c',
          fontFamily: "'Archivo', sans-serif"
        },
      }
  });

}); ///End
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 order-lg-2 order-md-2 order-sm-2 order-col-2 resultsBox">
 <div class="Task">
  <h3 class="resultsFont">Results</h3>
  <p class="descriptionFont" id="savings"></p>
 <hr />
  <canvas id="myChart" class="descriptionFont"></canvas>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you applied a size to the `<canvas>` via CSS rules?

Comment: Yes, no effect.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you fixed it? could you post your answer

Comment: same issue...any solutions?

Comment: As mentioned by @AndrewSteinheiser in a different thread,

"Try removing the legend from the pre-built component and implementing your own version of the legend. This way the graph can be the proper size and you can guarantee that the legend isn't affecting the graph."